# How do I make a dataframe propagated from lines in a large body of text with Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, text, dataset

I am trying to create a dataframe where every row has a line from a large body of text I have saved as a .txt (or otherwise) file.

I was thinking of making a function calling up every 10 or 20 words and adding as a new row, or adding it to a list of strings and then converting to a df, but I am coming up blank. Thank you ahead of time!

This will be used as in a classifier setting. There is no magic reason for 10 or 20, only just want to make sure I have a pretty even amount of words in every line rather than some rows have 1 sentence and others have a whole paragraph.

I have yet to write any code for this since I am not sure where to start.

Comment: What do you want this dataframe to look like? Dataframes usually hold tabular data and this doesn't sound like that. Is there some useful reason why every 10 words being a row is useful?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try something like this with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
N = 10 # <-- adjust here the number of words
​
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:file
    data = file.read().split()  #I used your post/question as the text file
​
df = pd.DataFrame({"text": [" ".join(data[i:i+N]) for i in range(0, len(data), N)]})
​
#just to show the number of words per row
df["nb_words"] = df["text"].str.count(" ").add(1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)
​
                                                      text  nb_words
0        I am trying to create a dataframe where every row        10
1                   has a line from a large body of text I        10
2          have saved as a .txt (or otherwise) file. I was        10
3     thinking of making a function calling up every 10 or        10
4              20 words and adding as a new row, or adding        10
5           it to a list of strings and then converting to        10
6                a df, but I am coming up blank. Thank you        10
7                 ahead of time! This will be used as in a        10
8   classifier setting. There is no magic reason for 10 or        10
9                 20, only just want to make sure I have a        10
10   pretty even amount of words in every line rather than        10
11       some rows have 1 sentence and others have a whole        10
12        paragraph. I have yet to write any code for this        10
13                     since I am not sure where to start.         8
```